# Sandboxing Multi-Thread Challenges

Tags: discussion, sandbox

I am currently sandboxing [a challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11709/56656) that will have two threads.

I was wondering if there was any good way to do Multi-thread challenges like [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers).  Typically I do one thread explaining the idea and get feedback on the idea rather than the formatting details and wording.  However I often want feedback on the details too.

What good ways are there for sandboxing a Multi-Thread challenge?

Answer (score 8):

### Post both threads in one sandbox post

For users who can see revisions of deleted answers, [here is an example](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/9156/9). The two threads belong together, so separate voting doesn't make sense... if votes deemed one part ready and the other not, you would not post one without the other. At the same time, posting them in one answer keeps all the information together, without others having to go looking for another sandbox answer. And finally, it also keeps the discussion in one place by having all comments on one answer. There might well be comments that affect both parts of the challenge, and it would be annoying if these were distributed randomly over both answers.